# php codeigniter i want to redirect this function print_view and also pass the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

php codeigniter i want to redirect this function print_view and also pass the data  `$this->db->insert('invoice_main',$datas);$result = $this->db->insert_id();`

```
Public function insert_invoice(){
    $item_name = $_POST['item'];
     $rate = $_POST['rate'];
     $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
     $tax = $_POST['tax'];
     $amount = $_POST['amount'];
     $invoice_id = $this->input->post('invoice_id');
     //$invoice_id++;
     $datas = array(
       'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
           'invoice_id' => $this->input->post('invoice_id'),
        'pt_opnum' => $this->input->post('pt_opnum'),
        'pt_uhid' => $this->input->post('pt_uhid'),
        'doc_name' => $this->input->post('doc_name'),
        'status'=>1
       );
     $this->db->insert('invoice_main',$datas);
     $result = $this->db->insert_id();
     for ($i=0; $i <count($item_name) ; $i++) {
       $data=array(
           'invoice_id' =>$invoice_id,
           'pt_name'=> $this->input->post('pt_opnum'),
           'date'=>date('d-m-Y'),
           'name'=>$item_name[$i],
           'rate'=>$rate[$i],
           'quantity'=>$quantity[$i],
           'tax'=>$tax[$i],
           'amount'=>$amount[$i],
           'sub_total'=>$_POST['sub_total'],
           'o_tax'=>$_POST['o_tax'],
           'grand_total'=>$_POST['grand_total'],
           'status'=>1
           );
       $this->db->insert('invoice_details',$data);
   }
   return($this->db->affected_rows()!=1)?false:true;
   $this->print_view($result);
}

public function print_view($result){
 redirect(base_url()."invoice/print_view/".$result);
 }
```

Comment: Are you following MVC architecture? If you are new in CI then please learn it well and follow its standards so you can get minimum issues, Now tell me this code is in a model or in a controller? And if you want to redirect then why there is return before the $this->print_view($result) which is wrong

Comment: see this link  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601460/should-i-call-redirect-from-within-my-controller-or-model-in-an-mvc-framework]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the any data with flashdata.

```
   $this->session->set_flashdata('something',$result);
```

On the other page you can access it

```
$something = $this->session->flashdata('something);
```

But on your case you don't have to use flash data, you can get the params from url and you can search on your DB.